# "which nvm" command (nvm installed via homebrew) doesn't return path

Tags: terminal, homebrew, nvm

I have installed nvm via homebrew. I have followed through the caveats:

```
mkdir ~/.nvm 
cp $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm-exec ~/.nvm/
```

AddED to my .zshrc file:

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

I have restarted my shell and when I type "which nvm" I get the file output instead of a file path locating the nvm version. I removed the package, reinstalled. All other "which" commands work.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

File output after typing "which nvm":

```
nvm () {
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]
    then
        nvm help
        return
    fi
    local GREP_OPTIONS
    GREP_OPTIONS=''
    local VERSION
    local ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS
    local ALIAS
    case $1 in
        ("help") echo
            echo "Node Version Manager"
            echo
            echo "Usage:"
            echo "  nvm help                              Show this message"
            echo "  nvm --version                         Print out the latest released version of nvm"
            echo "  nvm install [-s] <version>            Download and install a <version>, [-s] from source. Uses .nvmrc if available"
            echo "  nvm uninstall <version>               Uninstall a version"
            echo "  nvm use <version>                     Modify PATH to use <version>. Uses .nvmrc if available"
            echo "  nvm run <version> [<args>]            Run <version> with <args> as arguments. Uses .nvmrc if available for <version>"
            echo "  nvm current                           Display currently activated version"
            echo "  nvm ls                                List installed versions"
            echo "  nvm ls <version>                      List versions matching a given description"
            echo "  nvm ls-remote                         List remote versions available for install"
            echo "  nvm deactivate                        Undo effects of \`nvm\` on current shell"
            echo "  nvm alias [<pattern>]                 Show all aliases beginning with <pattern>"
            echo "  nvm alias <name> <version>            Set an alias named <name> pointing to <version>"
            echo "  nvm unalias <name>                    Deletes the alias named <name>"
            echo "  nvm reinstall-packages <version>      Reinstall global \`npm\` packages contained in <version> to current version"
            echo "  nvm unload                            Unload \`nvm\` from shell"
            echo "  nvm which [<version>]                 Display path to installed node version. Uses .nvmrc if available"
            echo
            echo "Example:"
            echo "  nvm install v0.10.32                  Install a specific version number"
            echo "  nvm use 0.10                          Use the latest available 0.10.x release"
            echo "  nvm run 0.10.32 app.js                Run app.js using node v0.10.32"
            echo "  nvm exec 0.10.32 node app.js          Run \`node app.js\` with the PATH pointing to node v0.10.32"
            echo "  nvm alias default 0.10.32             Set default node version on a shell"
            echo
            echo "Note:"
            echo "  to remove, delete, or uninstall nvm - just remove ~/.nvm, ~/.npm, and ~/.bower folders"
            echo ;;
        ("install"|"i") local nobinary
            local version_not_provided
            version_not_provided=0
            local provided_version
            local NVM_OS
            NVM_OS="$(nvm_get_os)"
            if ! nvm_has "curl" && ! nvm_has "wget"
            then
                echo 'nvm needs curl or wget to proceed.' >&2
                return 1
            fi
            if [ $# -lt 2 ]
            then
                version_not_provided=1
                nvm_rc_version
                if [ -z "$NVM_RC_VERSION" ]
                then
                    nvm help >&2
                    return 127
                fi
            fi
            shift
            nobinary=0
            if [ "_$1" = "_-s" ]
            then
                nobinary=1
                shift
            fi
            provided_version="$1"
            if [ -z "$provided_version" ]
            then
                if [ $version_not_provided -ne 1 ]
                then
                    nvm_rc_version
                fi
                provided_version="$NVM_RC_VERSION"
            else
                shift
            fi
            VERSION="$(nvm_remote_version "$provided_version")"
            if [ "_$VERSION" = "_N/A" ]
            then
                echo "Version '$provided_version' not found - try \`nvm ls-remote\` to browse available versions." >&2
                return 3
            fi
            ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS=''
            local PROVIDED_REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM
            local REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM
            while [ $# -ne 0 ]
            do
                case "$1" in
                    (--reinstall-packages-from=*) PROVIDED_REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM="$(echo "$1" | command cut -c 27-)"
                        REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM="$(nvm_version "$PROVIDED_REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM")"  ;;
                    (--copy-packages-from=*) PROVIDED_REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM="$(echo "$1" | command cut -c 22-)"
                        REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM="$(nvm_version "$PROVIDED_REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM")"  ;;
                    (*) ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS="$ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS $1"  ;;
                esac
                shift
            done
            if [ "_$(nvm_ensure_version_prefix "$PROVIDED_REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM")" = "_$VERSION" ]
            then
                echo "You can't reinstall global packages from the same version of node you're installing." >&2
                return 4
            elif [ ! -z "$PROVIDED_REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM" ] && [ "_$REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM" = "_N/A" ]
            then
                echo "If --reinstall-packages-from is provided, it must point to an installed version of node." >&2
                return 5
            fi
            local NVM_IOJS
            if nvm_is_iojs_version "$VERSION"
            then
                NVM_IOJS=true
            fi
            local VERSION_PATH
            VERSION_PATH="$(nvm_version_path "$VERSION")"
            if [ -d "$VERSION_PATH" ]
            then
                echo "$VERSION is already installed." >&2
                if nvm use "$VERSION" && [ ! -z "$REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM" ] && [ "_$REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM" != "_N/A" ]
                then
                    nvm reinstall-packages "$REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM"
                fi
                return $?
            fi
            if [ "_$NVM_OS" = "_freebsd" ]
            then
                nobinary=1
            elif [ "_$NVM_OS" = "_sunos" ] && [ "$NVM_IOJS" = true ]
            then
                nobinary=1
            fi
            local NVM_INSTALL_SUCCESS
            if [ $nobinary -ne 1 ] && nvm_binary_available "$VERSION"
            then
                if [ "$NVM_IOJS" = true ] && nvm_install_iojs_binary "$VERSION" "$REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM"
                then
                    NVM_INSTALL_SUCCESS=true
                elif [ "$NVM_IOJS" != true ] && nvm_install_node_binary "$VERSION" "$REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM"
                then
                    NVM_INSTALL_SUCCESS=true
                fi
            fi
            if [ "$NVM_INSTALL_SUCCESS" != true ]
            then
                if [ "$NVM_IOJS" = true ]
                then
                    echo "Installing iojs from source is not currently supported" >&2
                    return 105
                elif nvm_install_node_source "$VERSION" "$ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS"
                then
                    NVM_INSTALL_SUCCESS=true
                fi
            fi
            if [ "$NVM_INSTALL_SUCCESS" = true ] && nvm use "$VERSION"
            then
                if [ ! -z "$REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM" ] && [ "_$REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM" != "_N/A" ]
                then
                    nvm reinstall-packages "$REINSTALL_PACKAGES_FROM"
                fi
            fi
            return $? ;;
        ("uninstall") if [ $# -ne 2 ]
            then
                nvm help >&2
                return 127
            fi
            local PATTERN
            PATTERN="$2"
            case "_$PATTERN" in
                ("_$(nvm_iojs_prefix)"|"_$(nvm_iojs_prefix)-"|"_$(nvm_node_prefix)"|"_$(nvm_node_prefix)-") VERSION="$(nvm_version "$PATTERN")"  ;;
                (*) VERSION="$(nvm_version "$PATTERN")"  ;;
            esac
            if [ "_$VERSION" = "_$(nvm_ls_current)" ]
            then
                if nvm_is_iojs_version "$VERSION"
                then
                    echo "nvm: Cannot uninstall currently-active io.js version, $VERSION (inferred from $PATTERN)." >&2
                else
                    echo "nvm: Cannot uninstall currently-active node version, $VERSION (inferred from $PATTERN)." >&2
                fi
                return 1
            fi
            local VERSION_PATH
            VERSION_PATH="$(nvm_version_path "$VERSION")"
            if [ ! -d "$VERSION_PATH" ]
            then
                echo "$VERSION version is not installed..." >&2
                return
            fi
            t="$VERSION-$(nvm_get_os)-$(nvm_get_arch)"
            local NVM_PREFIX
            local NVM_SUCCESS_MSG
            if nvm_is_iojs_version "$VERSION"
            then
                NVM_PREFIX="$(nvm_iojs_prefix)"
                NVM_SUCCESS_MSG="Uninstalled io.js $(nvm_strip_iojs_prefix $VERSION)"
            else
                NVM_PREFIX="$(nvm_node_prefix)"
                NVM_SUCCESS_MSG="Uninstalled node $VERSION"
            fi
            command rm -rf "$NVM_DIR/src/$NVM_PREFIX-$VERSION" "$NVM_DIR/src/$NVM_PREFIX-$VERSION.tar.gz" "$NVM_DIR/bin/$NVM_PREFIX-${t}" "$NVM_DIR/bin/$NVM_PREFIX-${t}.tar.gz" "$VERSION_PATH" 2> /dev/null
            echo "$NVM_SUCCESS_MSG"
            for ALIAS in `command grep -l $VERSION "$(nvm_alias_path)/*" 2>/dev/null`
            do
                nvm unalias "$(command basename "$ALIAS")"
            done ;;
        ("deactivate") local NEWPATH
            NEWPATH="$(nvm_strip_path "$PATH" "/bin")"
            if [ "_$PATH" = "_$NEWPATH" ]
            then
                echo "Could not find $NVM_DIR/*/bin in \$PATH" >&2
            else
                export PATH="$NEWPATH"
                hash -r
                echo "$NVM_DIR/*/bin removed from \$PATH"
            fi
            NEWPATH="$(nvm_strip_path "$MANPATH" "/share/man")"
            if [ "_$MANPATH" = "_$NEWPATH" ]
            then
                echo "Could not find $NVM_DIR/*/share/man in \$MANPATH" >&2
            else
                export MANPATH="$NEWPATH"
                echo "$NVM_DIR/*/share/man removed from \$MANPATH"
            fi
            NEWPATH="$(nvm_strip_path "$NODE_PATH" "/lib/node_modules")"
            if [ "_$NODE_PATH" != "_$NEWPATH" ]
            then
                export NODE_PATH="$NEWPATH"
                echo "$NVM_DIR/*/lib/node_modules removed from \$NODE_PATH"
            fi ;;
        ("use") local PROVIDED_VERSION
            if [ $# -eq 1 ]
            then
                nvm_rc_version
                if [ -n "$NVM_RC_VERSION" ]
                then
                    PROVIDED_VERSION="$NVM_RC_VERSION"
                    VERSION="$(nvm_version "$PROVIDED_VERSION")"
                fi
            else
                local NVM_IOJS_PREFIX
                NVM_IOJS_PREFIX="$(nvm_iojs_prefix)"
                local NVM_NODE_PREFIX
                NVM_NODE_PREFIX="$(nvm_node_prefix)"
                PROVIDED_VERSION="$2"
                case "_$PROVIDED_VERSION" in
                    ("_$NVM_IOJS_PREFIX"|"_io.js") VERSION="$(nvm_version $NVM_IOJS_PREFIX)"  ;;
                    ("_system") VERSION="system"  ;;
                    (*) VERSION="$(nvm_version "$PROVIDED_VERSION")"  ;;
                esac
            fi
            if [ -z "$VERSION" ]
            then
                nvm help >&2
                return 127
            fi
            if [ "_$VERSION" = '_system' ]
            then
                if nvm_has_system_node && nvm deactivate > /dev/null 2>&1
                then
                    echo "Now using system version of node: $(node -v 2>/dev/null)$(nvm_print_npm_version)"
                    return
                elif nvm_has_system_iojs && nvm deactivate > /dev/null 2>&1
                then
                    echo "Now using system version of io.js: $(iojs --version 2>/dev/null)$(nvm_print_npm_version)"
                    return
                else
                    echo "System version of node not found." >&2
                    return 127
                fi
            elif [ "_$VERSION" = "_∞" ]
            then
                echo "The alias \"$PROVIDED_VERSION\" leads to an infinite loop. Aborting." >&2
                return 8
            fi
            nvm_ensure_version_installed "$PROVIDED_VERSION"
            EXIT_CODE=$?
            if [ "$EXIT_CODE" != "0" ]
            then
                return $EXIT_CODE
            fi
            local NVM_VERSION_DIR
            NVM_VERSION_DIR="$(nvm_version_path "$VERSION")"
            PATH="$(nvm_strip_path "$PATH" "/bin")"
            PATH="$(nvm_prepend_path "$PATH" "$NVM_VERSION_DIR/bin")"
            if nvm_has manpath
            then
                if [ -z "$MANPATH" ]
                then
                    MANPATH=$(manpath)
                fi
                MANPATH="$(nvm_strip_path "$MANPATH" "/share/man")"
                MANPATH="$(nvm_prepend_path "$MANPATH" "$NVM_VERSION_DIR/share/man")"
                export MANPATH
            fi
            export PATH
            hash -r
            export NVM_PATH="$NVM_VERSION_DIR/lib/node"
            export NVM_BIN="$NVM_VERSION_DIR/bin"
            if [ "$NVM_SYMLINK_CURRENT" = true ]
            then
                command rm -f "$NVM_DIR/current" && ln -s "$NVM_VERSION_DIR" "$NVM_DIR/current"
            fi
            if nvm_is_iojs_version "$VERSION"
            then
                echo "Now using io.js $(nvm_strip_iojs_prefix "$VERSION")$(nvm_print_npm_version)"
            else
                echo "Now using node $VERSION$(nvm_print_npm_version)"
            fi ;;
        ("run") local provided_version
            local has_checked_nvmrc
            has_checked_nvmrc=0
            shift
            if [ $# -lt 1 ]
            then
                nvm_rc_version && has_checked_nvmrc=1
                if [ -n "$NVM_RC_VERSION" ]
                then
                    VERSION="$(nvm_version "$NVM_RC_VERSION")"
                else
                    VERSION='N/A'
                fi
                if [ $VERSION = "N/A" ]
                then
                    nvm help >&2
                    return 127
                fi
            fi
            provided_version=$1
            if [ -n "$provided_version" ]
            then
                VERSION="$(nvm_version "$provided_version")"
                if [ "_$VERSION" = "_N/A" ] && ! nvm_is_valid_version "$provided_version"
                then
                    provided_version=''
                    if [ $has_checked_nvmrc -ne 1 ]
                    then
                        nvm_rc_version && has_checked_nvmrc=1
                    fi
                    VERSION="$(nvm_version "$NVM_RC_VERSION")"
                else
                    shift
                fi
            fi
            local NVM_IOJS
            if nvm_is_iojs_version "$VERSION"
            then
                NVM_IOJS=true
            fi
            local ARGS
            ARGS="$@"
            local OUTPUT
            local EXIT_CODE
            local ZHS_HAS_SHWORDSPLIT_UNSET
            ZHS_HAS_SHWORDSPLIT_UNSET=1
            if nvm_has "setopt"
            then
                ZHS_HAS_SHWORDSPLIT_UNSET=$(setopt | command grep shwordsplit > /dev/null ; echo $?)
                setopt shwordsplit
            fi
            if [ "_$VERSION" = "_N/A" ]
            then
                echo "$(nvm_ensure_version_prefix "$provided_version") is not installed yet" >&2
                EXIT_CODE=1
            elif [ -z "$ARGS" ]
            then
                if [ "$NVM_IOJS" = true ]
                then
                    nvm exec "$VERSION" iojs
                else
                    nvm exec "$VERSION" node
                fi
                EXIT_CODE="$?"
            elif [ "$NVM_IOJS" = true ]
            then
                echo "Running io.js $(nvm_strip_iojs_prefix "$VERSION")"
                OUTPUT="$(nvm use "$VERSION" >/dev/null && iojs $ARGS)"
                EXIT_CODE="$?"
            else
                echo "Running node $VERSION"
                OUTPUT="$(nvm use "$VERSION" >/dev/null && node $ARGS)"
                EXIT_CODE="$?"
            fi
            if [ $ZHS_HAS_SHWORDSPLIT_UNSET -eq 1 ] && nvm_has "unsetopt"
            then
                unsetopt shwordsplit
            fi
            if [ -n "$OUTPUT" ]
            then
                echo "$OUTPUT"
            fi
            return $EXIT_CODE ;;
        ("exec") shift
            local provided_version
            provided_version="$1"
            if [ -n "$provided_version" ]
            then
                VERSION="$(nvm_version "$provided_version")"
                if [ "_$VERSION" = "_N/A" ]
                then
                    nvm_rc_version
                    provided_version="$NVM_RC_VERSION"
                    VERSION="$(nvm_version "$provided_version")"
                else
                    shift
                fi
            fi
            nvm_ensure_version_installed "$provided_version"
            EXIT_CODE=$?
            if [ "$EXIT_CODE" != "0" ]
            then
                return $EXIT_CODE
            fi
            echo "Running node $VERSION"
            NODE_VERSION="$VERSION" $NVM_DIR/nvm-exec "$@" ;;
        ("ls"|"list") local NVM_LS_OUTPUT
            local NVM_LS_EXIT_CODE
            NVM_LS_OUTPUT=$(nvm_ls "$2")
            NVM_LS_EXIT_CODE=$?
            nvm_print_versions "$NVM_LS_OUTPUT"
            if [ $# -eq 1 ]
            then
                nvm alias
            fi
            return $NVM_LS_EXIT_CODE ;;
        ("ls-remote"|"list-remote") local PATTERN
            PATTERN="$2"
            local NVM_FLAVOR
            case "_$PATTERN" in
                ("_$(nvm_iojs_prefix)"|"_$(nvm_node_prefix)") NVM_FLAVOR="$PATTERN"
                    PATTERN="$3"  ;;
            esac
            local NVM_LS_REMOTE_EXIT_CODE
            NVM_LS_REMOTE_EXIT_CODE=0
            local NVM_LS_REMOTE_OUTPUT
            NVM_LS_REMOTE_OUTPUT=''
            if [ "_$NVM_FLAVOR" != "_$(nvm_iojs_prefix)" ]
            then
                NVM_LS_REMOTE_OUTPUT=$(nvm_ls_remote "$PATTERN")
                NVM_LS_REMOTE_EXIT_CODE=$?
            fi
            local NVM_LS_REMOTE_IOJS_EXIT_CODE
            NVM_LS_REMOTE_IOJS_EXIT_CODE=0
            local NVM_LS_REMOTE_IOJS_OUTPUT
            NVM_LS_REMOTE_IOJS_OUTPUT=''
            if [ "_$NVM_FLAVOR" != "_$(nvm_node_prefix)" ]
            then
                NVM_LS_REMOTE_IOJS_OUTPUT=$(nvm_ls_remote_iojs "$PATTERN")
                NVM_LS_REMOTE_IOJS_EXIT_CODE=$?
            fi
            local NVM_OUTPUT
            NVM_OUTPUT="$(echo "$NVM_LS_REMOTE_OUTPUT
$NVM_LS_REMOTE_IOJS_OUTPUT" | command grep -v "N/A" | sed '/^$/d')"
            if [ -n "$NVM_OUTPUT" ]
            then
                nvm_print_versions "$NVM_OUTPUT"
                return $NVM_LS_REMOTE_EXIT_CODE || $NVM_LS_REMOTE_IOJS_EXIT_CODE
            else
                nvm_print_versions "N/A"
                return 3
            fi ;;
        ("current") nvm_version current ;;
        ("which") local provided_version
            provided_version="$2"
            if [ $# -eq 1 ]
            then
                nvm_rc_version
                if [ -n "$NVM_RC_VERSION" ]
                then
                    provided_version="$NVM_RC_VERSION"
                    VERSION=$(nvm_version "$NVM_RC_VERSION")
                fi
            elif [ "_$2" != '_system' ]
            then
                VERSION="$(nvm_version "$provided_version")"
            else
                VERSION="$2"
            fi
            if [ -z "$VERSION" ]
            then
                nvm help >&2
                return 127
            fi
            if [ "_$VERSION" = '_system' ]
            then
                if nvm_has_system_iojs > /dev/null 2>&1 || nvm_has_system_node > /dev/null 2>&1
                then
                    local NVM_BIN
                    NVM_BIN="$(nvm use system >/dev/null 2>&1 && command which node)"
                    if [ -n "$NVM_BIN" ]
                    then
                        echo "$NVM_BIN"
                        return
                    else
                        return 1
                    fi
                else
                    echo "System version of node not found." >&2
                    return 127
                fi
            elif [ "_$VERSION" = "_∞" ]
            then
                echo "The alias \"$2\" leads to an infinite loop. Aborting." >&2
                return 8
            fi
            nvm_ensure_version_installed "$provided_version"
            EXIT_CODE=$?
            if [ "$EXIT_CODE" != "0" ]
            then
                return $EXIT_CODE
            fi
            local NVM_VERSION_DIR
            NVM_VERSION_DIR="$(nvm_version_path "$VERSION")"
            echo "$NVM_VERSION_DIR/bin/node" ;;
        ("alias") local NVM_ALIAS_DIR
            NVM_ALIAS_DIR="$(nvm_alias_path)"
            command mkdir -p "$NVM_ALIAS_DIR"
            if [ $# -le 2 ]
            then
                local DEST
                for ALIAS_PATH in "$NVM_ALIAS_DIR"/"$2"*
                do
                    ALIAS="$(command basename "$ALIAS_PATH")"
                    DEST="$(nvm_alias "$ALIAS" 2> /dev/null)"
                    if [ -n "$DEST" ]
                    then
                        VERSION="$(nvm_version "$DEST")"
                        if [ "_$DEST" = "_$VERSION" ]
                        then
                            echo "$ALIAS -> $DEST"
                        else
                            echo "$ALIAS -> $DEST (-> $VERSION)"
                        fi
                    fi
                done
                for ALIAS in "$(nvm_node_prefix)" "stable" "unstable" "$(nvm_iojs_prefix)"
                do
                    if [ ! -f "$NVM_ALIAS_DIR/$ALIAS" ]
                    then
                        if [ $# -lt 2 ] || [ "~$ALIAS" = "~$2" ]
                        then
                            DEST="$(nvm_print_implicit_alias local "$ALIAS")"
                            if [ "_$DEST" != "_" ]
                            then
                                VERSION="$(nvm_version "$DEST")"
                                echo "$ALIAS -> $DEST (-> $VERSION) (default)"
                            fi
                        fi
                    fi
                done
                return
            fi
            if [ -z "$3" ]
            then
                command rm -f "$NVM_ALIAS_DIR/$2"
                echo "$2 -> *poof*"
                return
            fi
            VERSION="$(nvm_version "$3")"
            if [ $? -ne 0 ]
            then
                echo "! WARNING: Version '$3' does not exist." >&2
            fi
            echo "$3" | tee "$NVM_ALIAS_DIR/$2" > /dev/null
            if [ ! "_$3" = "_$VERSION" ]
            then
                echo "$2 -> $3 (-> $VERSION)"
            else
                echo "$2 -> $3"
            fi ;;
        ("unalias") local NVM_ALIAS_DIR
            NVM_ALIAS_DIR="$(nvm_alias_path)"
            command mkdir -p "$NVM_ALIAS_DIR"
            if [ $# -ne 2 ]
            then
                nvm help >&2
                return 127
            fi
            [ ! -f "$NVM_ALIAS_DIR/$2" ] && echo "Alias $2 doesn't exist!" >&2 && return
            command rm -f "$NVM_ALIAS_DIR/$2"
            echo "Deleted alias $2" ;;
        ("reinstall-packages"|"copy-packages") if [ $# -ne 2 ]
            then
                nvm help >&2
                return 127
            fi
            local PROVIDED_VERSION
            PROVIDED_VERSION="$2"
            if [ "$PROVIDED_VERSION" = "$(nvm_ls_current)" ] || [ "$(nvm_version "$PROVIDED_VERSION")" = "$(nvm_ls_current)" ]
            then
                echo 'Can not reinstall packages from the current version of node.' >&2
                return 2
            fi
            local NPMLIST
            if [ "_$PROVIDED_VERSION" = "_system" ]
            then
                if ! nvm_has_system_node && ! nvm_has_system_iojs
                then
                    echo 'No system version of node or io.js detected.' >&2
                    return 3
                fi
                NPMLIST=$(nvm deactivate > /dev/null && npm list -g --depth=0 | command tail -n +2)
            else
                local VERSION
                VERSION="$(nvm_version "$PROVIDED_VERSION")"
                NPMLIST=$(nvm use "$VERSION" > /dev/null && npm list -g --depth=0 | command tail -n +2)
            fi
            local INSTALLS
            INSTALLS=$(echo "$NPMLIST" | command sed -e '/ -> / d' -e 's/^.* \(.*\)@.*/\1/' -e '/^npm$/ d' | command xargs)
            echo "Copying global packages from $VERSION..."
            echo "$INSTALLS" | command xargs npm install -g --quiet
            local LINKS
            LINKS=$(echo "$NPMLIST" | command sed -n 's/.* -> \(.*\)/\1/ p')
            echo "Linking global packages from $VERSION..."
            for LINK in $LINKS
            do
                (
                    cd "$LINK" && npm link
                )
            done ;;
        ("clear-cache") command rm -f $NVM_DIR/v* "$(nvm_version_dir)" 2> /dev/null
            echo "Cache cleared." ;;
        ("version") nvm_version $2 ;;
        ("--version") echo "0.25.1" ;;
        ("unload") unset -f nvm nvm_print_versions nvm_checksum nvm_iojs_prefix nvm_node_prefix nvm_add_iojs_prefix nvm_strip_iojs_prefix nvm_is_iojs_version nvm_ls_remote nvm_ls nvm_remote_version nvm_remote_versions nvm_version nvm_rc_version nvm_version_greater nvm_version_greater_than_or_equal_to nvm_supports_source_options > /dev/null 2>&1
            unset RC_VERSION NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR NVM_DIR NVM_CD_FLAGS > /dev/null 2>&1 ;;
        (*) nvm help >&2
            return 127 ;;
    esac
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing `source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh` exports `nvm()` [function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) into your shell environment. It's not a reference to an executable, but the function whose contents you see when you do `which nvm`.

Comment: I figured something like that was going on. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I was mucking around figuring out which file to edit. This is much easier.